# Reading in column headers from different sheets with slight variance

Tags: excel, vba

Is this the right approach?

I have a handful of sheets from different providers for a mostly overlapping list of products.

I want to be able to read in the data from these providers and compile a single master sheet that can compare the prices from each of these in relation to the products that I currently stock (not all products listed by provider are ones I stock).

The issue with this is that not all providers supply the same format or even exact column headers in their data sheet (e.g. Price, Price_$, Price1, as column headers from different providers referring to the same column in their data).

Sometimes providers even change the format in which they present their headers, inc name changes. e.g. one month its Price, the next its Price1.

It occurs to me that the way to go about this is to compile a list of potential header names based on previous variants and to try and scan new price sheets, from the providers, with this list as a reference in order to indentify the columns correctly. That would then allow me to compile the information correctly in my mew master sheet to then be able to perform price checks etc and find the best deals amongst the providers.

Its been a while since Ive done anything in Excel (mainly been working with Google Sheets lately).
From what I gather this would be in VBA.

I guess my question is "Does this approach seem like the right way to go about it? and is VBA the right coding approach?"

Any comments, pointers or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Different Headers for the Same Data

- I wrote this a few days ago, I guess, for a question that got closed.

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Loops through a list of strings ('Headers') and attempts to find
'               a match in a cell of a row ('RowNumber') of a worksheet ('ws').
'               Returns the column number of the cell of the first found string.
'               Returns 0 if there is no match.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetFirstHeaderColumn( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal RowNumber As Long, _
    ParamArray Headers() As Variant) _
As Long
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber < 1 Or RowNumber > ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = ws.Rows(RowNumber)
    
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
        cIndex = Application.Match(CStr(Headers(n)), rrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            GetFirstHeaderColumn = cIndex
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    
End Function
```

- You could utilize it in the following way.

```vb
Sub GetFirstHeaderColumnTEST()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim Col1 As Long
    Col1 = GetFirstHeaderColumn(ws, FirstRow, "Price", "Price1")
    If Col1 > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Col1
    Else ' non of the headers were found
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    End If

    Dim Col2 As Long
    Col2 = GetFirstHeaderColumn(ws, FirstRow, "Sales", "Amount", "Sold")
    If Col1 > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Col2
    Else ' non of the headers were found
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    End If
    
End Sub
```